# Can I query the Github API for my repository quota?

Tags: github, github-api, quota

I'm working on an app that creates private Github repositories (among other things). Every once in a while, we are over quota with our private repos.

I'd like to know how many repositories we have left *before* making the API call that will fail.

Can that be done, using the Github API? I couldn't find anything in [the documentation](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/), but that's doesn't mean it's not possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awendt, I'm not quite familiar with private quotas, but authenticated users receive a Plan object when the API returns the call to `/user`. This will tell you what plan you have and will tell you how many `private_repos` you're allowed. With that information and the information from `/user` which tells you how many private repos you currently have, you should be able to figure it out.

Then again, you could use [`github3.py`](http://github3py.rtfd.org) and you'd have the User object, with the plan attribute and could use those two together as described above.

**Disclaimer** I'm github3.py's author.

Comment: Perfect! According to [http://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-the-authenticated-user](the documentation), I **do** get a "plan" sub-hash. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Glad to help. Probably should have linked to those docs instead of answering from memory though. Sorry about that.

Comment: ...except that the request doesn't return exactly what Github documented :(

Comment: What are you seeing that is different?

Comment: Well, most importantly, there's no "plan" key in the hash I get back.

Comment: Hm, it could be you're sending a different media type for the header, i.e., not using beta or v3.

Comment: Also, this only works for the authenticated user, not for other users.

Comment: Darn: `curl -H "Authorization: token OAUTH_TOKEN https://api.github.com/user` does not include the "plan" hash, but `curl -u awendt https://api.github.com/user` does. :(

Comment: I contacted Github support about this.

Comment: If you copied the former curl command directly, did you not close the `"`? Or did you just mistype it here? (I tend to believe the latter.) Also, is it safe to assume the token has the `user` scope?

Comment: @awendt I just tried (using my own github3.py wrapper) and used a token that I knew had the `user` scope attributed. I think that may be instead your issue.

Comment: Yes, scopes! That's what Github support also says. That's *got* to be it!

Comment: I'm happy to help and yet a bit disturbed by how well I know GitHub's API without having to reference the docs...